# How do you set up a Python WSGI server under IIS?

Tags: python, iis, deployment, windows-server, iis-modules

I work in a Windows environment and would prefer to deploy code to IIS. At the same time I would like to code in Python.

Having read that IIS can run fastCGI application, I went to the IIS site where it describes in detail how to get PHP up and running but not much about anything else.

Does anyone have experience getting a **Python** framework **running under IIS** using something other that plain old CGI?

If so can you explain to direct me to some instructions on setting this up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to use FastCGI. There exists a [ISAPI extension for WSGI](https://github.com/hexdump42/isapi-wsgi).

Comment: This answer is from 6 years ago. The project in the provided link has been last updated in 2010. Is there anything new on the Python-under-IIS front?

Comment: Same question. It's crazy when a great project just gets ... dropped. Come on MS! Python is increasing in popularity.

Answer (score 15):

Microsoft itself develops [wfastcgi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi) ([source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/tree/master/Python/Product/WFastCgi)) to host Python code on IIS.

Comment: Microsoft seems to take the same approach for Azure amd Python: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-python-django-web-app/

Comment: It's somewhat disengenous, if you go to the wfastcgi web page, and click on "Homepage" it shows you Azure. The implication is forget Windows, and go to Azure hosting.

That doesn't answer the question Microsoft ...

Answer (score 4):

We can use iiswsgi framework to setup WSGI over IIS since it is compatible with IIS web server's FastCGI protocol.It's bundled with distutils for building, distribution and installing packages with the help of Microsoft Web Deploy and Web Platform Installer.

For more info refer the following link:

[Serving Python WSGI applications natively from IIS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iiswsgi#serving-python-wsgi-applications-natively-from-iis)

Comment: @Georg Scholly this one is some what latest when compared to other documents above

Comment: wfastcgi is actually the latest, as iiswsgi's been abandoned *longer* (sigh)